Jest testing error: TypeError: (0 , import_redux2.combineReducers) is not a function
Here is an error that I'm unable to fix for weeks.
I'm trying to test my <App /> component using Jest (29.7.0).
The error I'm getting is:
TypeError: (0 , import_redux2.combineReducers) is not a function

      10 |
    > 11 | export const store = configureStore({
         |                                    ^
      12 |   reducer: {
      13 |     app: appReducer,
      14 |     configuration: configurationReducer,

      at configureStore (node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/configureStore.ts:165:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/store.js:11:36)
      at Object.require (src/components/alarmProfiles/AlarmProfileDetails.js:14:1)
      at Object.require (src/components/index.js:13:1)
      at Object.require (src/layouts/defaultLayout/DefaultLayout.js:4:1)
      at Object.require (src/layouts/index.js:1:1)
      at Object.require (src/pages/administrationPage/AdministrationPage.js:1:1)
      at Object.require (src/pages/index.js:1:1)
      at Object.require (src/App.js:7:1)
      at Object.require (src/tests/App.test.js:5:1)

That TypeError is pointing to my /redux/store.js, but I'm not even using combineReducers (I'm aware that configureStore calls it).
However, redux works normally in my web application and I'm getting no errors regarding something similar, so I'm suspecting a build issue.
This is my App.test.js:
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from '../App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import { languages } from 'lang';
import { selectLocale } from 'utils';
import { store } from 'redux/store';

const language = 'en';
test('renders ESG on the screen', () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <IntlProvider locale={selectLocale(language, true)} messages={languages[language]}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </IntlProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
  const text = screen.getByText(/map/i);
  expect(text).toBeInTheDocument();
});


I tried modifying my jest configuration but with no sign of improvement.
//package.json:
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!(ol|react-grid-layout|d3(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?|uuid|swiper|ssr-window|babel(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?|@babel(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?|@reduxjs/toolkit|redux|redux-thunk|react-redux)/).+\\.js$"
    ]
  }

Also, my App.js:
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectInitDone, selectLanguage } from 'redux/appSlice';
import {
  MapPage,
  SplashPage,
} from 'pages';
import { PageError, PageLoading } from 'components';
import { languages } from 'lang';
import { selectLocale } from 'utils';
import { selectThemeMode } from 'redux/appSlice';


const App = () => {
  const language = useSelector(selectLanguage);
  const initDone = useSelector(selectInitDone);
  const themeMode = useSelector(selectThemeMode)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (themeMode === 'dark') {
      document.body.classList.remove("light");
      document.body.classList.add("dark");
    }
    else if (themeMode === 'light') {
      document.body.classList.add("light");
      document.body.classList.remove("dark");
    }
    else return () => {
      document.body.classList.remove("light");
      document.body.classList.remove("dark");
    }
  }, [themeMode]);

  const renderApp = useCallback(() => {
    if (initDone === 'failed') return <PageError messageId="ERROR.FETCHING_DATA" />;
    else if (initDone) return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="dashboard" />} />
          <Route path="map" element={<MapPage />} />
          <Route path="/*" element={<SplashPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
    else return <PageLoading messageId="SPLASH.WAIT" />;

  }, [initDone]);


  const onIntlError = (error) => {
    if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <IntlProvider locale={selectLocale(language, true)} messages={languages[language]} onError={onIntlError}>
      {renderApp()}
    </IntlProvider>

  );
}
export default App;

